# Debugging Servlets in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt, tomcat, servlets

I have created a web application using the Google Web Toolkit that is able to receive some data by a mobile client via Http Post. The transmission of the data works well and also the server / client communication using GWT RPC is no problem at all.

However, I need to debug the webserver when receiving data from the mobile device. As I am using Hibernate and MySQL within the web application I do not use the Google App Engine. So if I deploy the web application in local host mode it is only accessible on the localhost:8888.

Now, if I send data from the mobile phone, I have to send it to the locally assign IP address as the localhost of the mobile phone emulator is not the localhost of the computer, where the web application is running. To ensure that everything works, I tried to do some posts outside the emulator (on the machine the emulator is running on). This works, but how can I post from the emulator to my web application?

How can I get access to debug my system? I've already tried to deploy the final application to a tomcat server and use remote debugging, but that fails too.

Best regards,
Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I understand your question correctly, the real problem isn't debugging the app on the servlet, the real problem that you're looking at is debugging from a mobile phone.  When the mobile phone hits your local network (I'm guessing you're pointing at 192.168.*.*?) you are accessing the compiled GWT code that does not communicate with the debugger.

Put another way, when you debug locally using a browser, you are actually not running compiled GWT code, but instrumented code that is executed with the GWT Debugging Plugin, that happens to work exactly like compiled GWT code. (mostly).  So while your local version has "?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997" or the like, your mobile phone version cannot do the same, and cannot thus communicate with the debugger.

The best that I've been able to do is to use logging extensively.  If you're using an iOS device and change the settings are your safari, it can output logs for you from mobile safari.  Also, if you're using the Android debugger with a WebView app, you can attach a listener for log messages and then ferry them on to the ADB and view those in Eclipse.  Definitely not as good as a debugger, but that's the best I've come up with so far, and if anyone has a better solution I would *love* to know it :)

Hope that helps!